# Recursion ( kind of sub-set sum, but not exactly ) - True if can buy pens at exact price, else False

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming

I have this question:
you have a list of [7,9,11] pens.
you have a function:

```
def can_i_buy(x):
```

you need to check whether or not if you can buy the exact amount.
for example, I have X=23
I can buy `1*9, 2*7`
I just need to return True if it is able, false else.
I saw the answer, they did it brute force with 3 for loops ( crazy ).
I tried recursion, it is good, but seems like it is long + duplicated parts + its not exactly good, cus I don't know where to put the False statement.. what is my exit point.
The code works, but not exactly.

```
def can_i_buy(x):  # 23
return helper(x, [7,9,11])
def helper(x, lst):
    if x == 0:
        return True
    if x < 0:    
        return
    take_1 = helper(x - lst[0], lst)
    if take_1 == True:
         return take_1
    take_2 = helper(x - lst[1], lst)
    if take_2 == True:
        return take_2
    take_3 = helper(x - lst[2], lst)
    if take_3 == True:
        return take_3
```

How to fix it? also, what is my thought on the exit statement here? I dont know how to exit it... Where should I put false, and how?

Edit: added prints + outputs

```
print(can_i_buy(24))
print(can_i_buy(23))
print(can_i_buy(7))
print(can_i_buy(14))
```

output:

```
None
True
True
True
```

I should receive at none - False. but I dont know where to put the False statement... when all the recursion end, I dont know how to put it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  "The code works, but not exactly"?   I'm not sure I understand that.  Please include the expected output and actual output.

Comment: It is well-known problem. See what is Unbounded knapsack, it could be solved using dynamic programming.

Comment: @funnydman Hi, thanks, but I still wanna know why my code is not "good enough", afterall, I need to learn myself, not to see the answer :\ 
( although, I will yea check it, the knapsack problem is known to me, but I will see the unbounded, first time hearing it )

Comment: " but I still wanna know why my code is not "good enough"" Think carefully about the line of code that just says `return`. What do you expect it to return? Why? Suppose that we get there as a result of the recursive call `take_1 = helper(x - lst[0], lst)`. What will be the value of `take_1`? Suppose that none of `take_1`, `take_2` or `take_3` is true, on a given call to the function; what do you expect to happen? The function will reach the end, right? And then what is returned? What do you suppose should be returned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The recursive call should be made with each price subtracted from `x`, until `x` is either 0 (in which case return `True`) or less than 0 (in which case return `False`):

```
def can_i_buy(x, lst):
    return not x or x > 0 and any(can_i_buy(x - i, lst) for i in lst)
```

If you just want your code fixed, you can return `False` at the end of the function when all conditions that would return `True` fall through:

```
def helper(x, lst):
    if x == 0:
        return True
    if x > 0:    
        take_1 = helper(x - lst[0], lst)
        if take_1 == True:
             return take_1
        take_2 = helper(x - lst[1], lst)
        if take_2 == True:
            return take_2
        take_3 = helper(x - lst[2], lst)
        if take_3 == True:
            return take_3
    return False
```

Or if you are allowed to make a `for` loop:

```
def helper(x, lst):
    if x == 0:
        return True
    if x > 0:
        for i in lst:
            if helper(x - i, lst):
                return True
    return False
```

Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing/MortifiedImmediateCheckpoint

Answer (score 0):

This problem is a special case of unbounded knapsack where repetition of items is allowed. It's similar to coin change (or [change-making](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change-making_problem)) problem but instead of finding the minimum number of coins that add up to the given amount you just need to find whether it's possible. These kinds of problems have dynamic-programming nature and usually solved via recursion.

#### Intuition:

Basically, brute force is the right way to go when you first time encounter such problem. For example, we have a list of values `[11, 9, 7]` and we want to find out if is it possible to get `23` using sums of those coins. We can explore every possible combination to check that.

#### Brute force

It's relatively easy to come up with brute force solution, recursion here is quite straightforward:

```
def can_i_buy(alist, target):
    if target == 0:
        return True
    if target < 0:
        return False

    for i in range(len(alist)):
        if can_i_buy(alist, target - alist[i]):
            return True

    return False
```

I draw a function call graph to show you what happens here (I didn't put here all branches to make it more compact):

[image]

I bet you can easily find unneeded work here, right? Take a look at green and red points, if we already computed result for node with value `5` (the same for `7`) do we really need to compute it again later? Can we somehow cache the previously calculated result? Yes, we can via memoization (you can also use `@cache` decorator instead of explicit cache).

#### Top-down with memoization

```
memo = {}


def can_i_buy(alist, target):
    if target == 0:
        return True
    if target < 0:
        return False
    if target in memo:
        return memo[target]

    for i in range(len(alist)):
        diff = target - alist[i]
        memo[diff] = can_i_buy(alist, diff)
        if memo[diff]:
            return True

    return False


print(can_i_buy([11, 9, 7], 23))


print(memo) # {-10: False, -8: False, -6: False, 1: False, -4: False, 3: False, -2: False, 5: False, 12: False, 0: True, 7: True, 14: True}
```

There's also one approach that is called bottom-up. Usually, it's harder to come up with, but it better shows relations between subproblems.

#### Bottom-Up

```
def can_i_buy(target):
    dp = [True] + [False] * target

    for num in range(1, target + 1):
        for coin in alist:
            if num - coin >= 0:
                dp[num] = dp[num] or dp[num - coin]
    return dp[target]
```

You can also use breadh-first search approach, it is very similar to the top-down approach.

#### Breadth-first

```
from collections import deque


def can_i_buy(alist, target):
    seen = set()
    queue = deque([target])
    while queue:
        t = queue.popleft()
        if t == 0:
            return True

        for val in alist:
            diff = t - val
            if diff >= 0 and diff not in seen:
                queue.append(t - val)
                seen.add(diff)
    return False
```

Comment: ow.. we have learned it just for a few minutes, loop inside a reucrsion, the teacher said it was risky doing it, so if you must not use it, it was said we should prefer not to use it ( I suffered by it myself, while trying a loop on recursion once, I had great troubles :\ )
but thanks!

Comment: "Loop inside a recursion is risky" - let me remember this outline:) If you don't want to have loop, use two recursive calls and pass the index through them

Comment: How is this DP? And it's very inefficient, something as small as `can_i_buy([2, 4], 69)` already takes over 10 seconds...

Comment: @Kelly I guess memoization can help?

Answer (score 0):

I used this technique which combined breadth-first search and dynamic programming to solve these kinds of problems. You can change it depending on your use cases(for example if we need to return how we create the value).

```
def can_i_buy(target_value, values):
    possible_values = {0: True}
    values_to_be_handled = [0]

    while values_to_be_handled:
        value = values_to_be_handled.pop(0)
        if value == target_value:
            return True
        for val in values:
            next_value = value + val
            if next_value > target_value:
                continue
            if next_value not in possible_values:
                possible_values[next_value] = True
                values_to_be_handled.append(next_value)

    return None
```

Answer (score 0):

> I just need to return True if it is able, false else.

The way we handle this using *dynamic programming*, properly, is:

- Initialize an array (list, in Python) of booleans N to false (except for a true value at 0, since of course we can spend $0 exactly), where the meaning is that `N[i]` tells us whether we can buy pens with `i` dollars.
- Iterate forwards through the array: if we find a false value while iterating, then the answer is false for that `i` value. Otherwise, it is true for that `i` value **and** we update further positions in the array, to indicate that we found a solution for those `i` values as well. (That is: once we know we can buy pens with $11 exactly, we also know that we can buy pens with $11+7, $11+9, and $11+11 exactly, so we fill in those values for when we get to them.

It looks like, for example:

```
def canibuy(dollars, pen_costs):
    # To find out for example if we can spend $23, we need 24 booleans,
    # representing the results for 0 to 23 *inclusive*.
    results = [True] + [False] * dollars
    for amount in range(len(results)):
        if results[amount]:
            # we can spend this amount exactly, so also update other values.
            for pen_cost in pen_costs:
                if (amount + pen_cost) < len(results):
                    results[amount + pen_cost] = True
    return results[-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

> Where should I put false, and how?

Everywhere that `False` should be returned. For example:

```
    if x < 0:    
        return
```

The underlying logic is: "if the amount of money to be spent is less than $0, then we know that we cannot do it". So - the result should be `False`, the value that indicates that we cannot do it. So we should write `return False` instead.

We should also return `False` at the end of the function, because if we get there, it means that we did not find a way to spend the money by our recursive algorithm. If we can't spend the remainder of the money after buying any of the possible pens, *then we know that we cannot spend the money*, and thus `False` is the correct return value.